# How do I play apple podcast inside my App

Tags: ios, swift, sdk, podcast

There is a lot of resources for using Apple Music SDK to play music in App, but I can’t find any resource for playing apple podcast. Is it even possible to play podcasts from inside my app?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for Apple Podcasts Embed.

These are the resources, that I know of, that can lead you to the right direction:

- **Apple Podcasts web embed:** https://podcasters.apple.com/874-introducing-the-apple-podcasts-web-embed
- **Apple Podcasts embed player:** https://podcasters.apple.com/support/889-apple-podcasts-embed-player
- **Apple Podcasts Marketing Tool:** https://tools.applemediaservices.com/apple-podcasts
- **Podcast RSS feed requirements:** https://podcasters.apple.com/support/823-podcast-requirements